# Windows Sleep Microseconds for Low Latency Thread Communication

Tags: windows, multithreading, communication, sleep, low-latency

Is there any way I could suspend the thread for 1-2 microseconds? (Note 1 microsecond = 1/1000 miliseond). I know this question has been asked but so far there is no good answer for this. Here is my situation why I need this:

I have a server with several threads running to serve client's requests. Requests are sent by other thread through shared memory which occurs occasionally. However, once request is sent it needs to be processed ASAP. So, I need a fast way to notify one of the serving threads when request is queued in shared memory.

Windows event object was used but it takes 6-7us from SetEvent() to WaitForSingleObject() return on my machine (tried to set process/thread priority but still not much improvement). I tried to use a busy loop to let the serving threads keep pooling the memory which lower the latency to 1-2us, which is good enough, but it burns the CPU while the requests are only sent like once per minutes. If I could insert a micro/nano second sleep into the loop I could at least get my CPU free while keep the latency low.

I would be glad if anyone could suggest me another way to do the thread communication with latency lower than 2us. Thanks

Comment: Don't go into this direction. Alone the need for such a sleep in such a scenario (which is not a real-time application) indicates IMHO a broken design.

Comment: I think this can only be done reliably in the "Kernel Ring".

Comment: There is Thread.SpinWait() which is a "less expensive way" to do busy-waiting. But: _"requests are only sent like once per minutes"_ means don't do it. How come you have µs problems in a minute-based situation?

Comment: even 1ms is already asking too much

Comment: 'However, once request is sent it needs to be processed ASAP' why does it need to be signaled so quickly after such a long wait?  Complex desktop OS like Windows are not real-time systems - they don't do low latency.  Inter-thread comms response in the ns or low us range are not easily attainable.  TBH, 6-7us to make a high-priority thread running when signalled seems a bit long, even for Windows.

Comment: Just a thought - if your test box has any CPU power-economy settings, check that it's set to 'maximum performance' and not 'power down and stop everything in an unused core'.

Comment: The best I got iirc was millisecond or deci-millisecond precision (average, no guarantees from OS!) for waiting using a [multimedia timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd742877(v=vs.85).aspx) and using features of the [Multimedia Class Scheduler Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684247(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Sorry for coming back late. For those who's curious why it would be µs problems in a minute-based situation: each worker thread holding session to trading floor, when trading opportunity pop a request will be written on shared memory queue triggering one of the worker threads. The worker thread will have to wake ASAP and send the request to trading floor via API. However, the API called is blocking and will not be returned before 200ms. Trading opportunity is something happened occasionally but once it pops, several requests generated and so needed to be handled by several workers in µs/ns.

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot sleep a thread for that period.

Last time I tested (about 10 years ago, mind, on Windows 2000) sleeping for less than 13ms resulted in a sleep of either 0ms or 13ms.

Windows is not a real-time operating system.

You can spin your thread for that time period, using the high resolution timer.

Honestly though it almost certainly means the design is flawed.

I've just read the post now; the problem is the thread model.  You have a worker pool.  This inherently requires cross-thread communication, which is problematic since it requires OS services.  An alternative is one thread per core, with symmetry between those threads, e.g. they all do everything and you share the load between them.